# ¿Cómo hago para poner un método OnClick en la parte lógica de un Activity que se extiende de Fragment en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-fragment, onclick

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout,container,false);
}

public void Enter(View view){
    EditText et1=(EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textview);

    String s1=et1.getText().toString();

    tv1.setText(s1);
}
}
```

**Osea el método onClick "Enter" no me lo reconoce en esta activity porque en vez de extenderlo a AppCompatActivity lo extendí a Fragment, lo necesito en Fragment obligatoriamente.
He visto que Fragment tiene distintos comandos que hacen lo mismo que los comandos que tiene AppCompatActivity, los he investigado todos pero me falta ver cómo es aquí en Fragment el comando para un método OnClick, ese comando no lo he encontrado en ninguna parte de internet y por eso he escrito este post. ¿Cuál es la solución a esto?**

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que quieres es lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout,container,false);

EditText et1=view.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
TextView tv1=view.findViewById(R.id.textview);

//ESTE SERÁ TU MÉTODO ONCLICK
et1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //LO QUE QUIERAS HACER
        }
    });

return view;
}
```

Comment: No me funcionó, con este comando al compilar la app me salió una advertencia que decía: Note: AndroidStudioProjects\...\ui\main\SectionsPagerAdapter.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Luego cuando intenté abrir la app se me cerró al abrirla, tengo Android 5.1.1 y parece que este comando es obsoleto

Comment: Nunca vi algo como "deprecated API". Seguramente estás en una versión muy vieja. Ve a build.graddle (app) y fíjate que número tiene el minSdkVersion. Sino busca ese error en stack overflow que seguro ya lo preguntaron